# How to set Bootstrap's hero unit height to 100%?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a very simple landing page using Bootstrap. The idea is to have a hero unit text element covering the entire page regardless of the window size. The `width: 100%;` CSS instruction works great, but `height: 100%;` has no effect – the hero unit element is still about 200px high and is attached to the top of the window. How do I set hero unit's height to 100%? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `height:100%` on `html` and `body` tags, and if the hero div has a parent, it'll need that as well.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/xExSE/

Comment: Thanks, @christopher-marshall! And should I then center the text vertically using vertical-align?

Comment: You can try, Their may be different ways to solve that depending on your layout. e.g. line-height equal to height of container, a JS solution depending on window size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" />
  <style>
    .hero-unit {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <h1>Full Page Hero!</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```